# Term for a reliable source of income

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

What is a term for a reliable, sustainable, lucrative source of income? Similar to "cash cow" but not something you have to wait for.

Comment: A [cash cow](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cash_cow) is not something you wait for; it's something you milk regularly. It's exactly the term you're looking for.

Comment: @Andrew Leach Udderly true.

Comment: How does this not deserve to be closed because it meets the criteria of [this guidance from Stack Exchange Management](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity)? It's just a guess-me thesaurus hunt.

Answer (score -1):

An [annuity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/annuity) is generally considered a reliable source of income:

> a sum of money payable yearly or at other regular intervals

(M-W)